# Divide a 2D depth image into non-overlapping rectangular areas of similar values

Tags: python, optimization, computational-geometry, image-segmentation, ransac

I am trying to segment a 2D depth image into non-overlapping rectangular areas of similar values as shown in the example:
[image: Fit rectangles to a 2D depth image]

In this example, the depth image is segmented into four rectangles: 4by3by6 yellow, 2by4by15 green, 4by2by8 orange, and 2by2by3 blue. Note that there is a min length and width limit to the rectangles, in this case, 2, so that the lower right corner is segmented into one area instead of two.

This is a simple example, the depth map can be a lot more complex than this. This is quite a challenging problem I don't expect it to be solved to optimality, but any solution more optimized than a grid of fixed resolution is appreciated.

I imagine this to be solved by some RANSAC process, similar to plane fitting, but I haven't figured out exactly how to do that. The problem also resembles image segmentation, where each segment is rectangular in shape and does not overlap.

Comment: You haven't actually asked any specific questions whatsoever; you've stated "any solution...is appreciated" so to me that indicates you are telling us to post solutions given the requirements laid out in your post. You have no [mre], no solid program design, no code whatsoever besides the quick example - just saying, this post might not get much attention as a result, based on my experience here. A lot of people are going to just interpret this as you pasting in homework and just expecting someone to do all the work for you.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comment. I believe I do have a minimal example listed including one possible solution. The problem is quite open-ended, I am not looking for a complete solution or code (although that will be great), but just some thoughts on how the problem can be approached.  If I can form a more concrete solution I will also update it here. As for the concern that this might be homework, I guess a homework problem would be defined a lot more rigorously.

Comment: In general, you can't optimize two criteria at a time. There is a solution with a single cuboid, and there is a solution with volume zero, and lots of intermediate solutions.

Comment: What do you call the "volume sum" ?

Comment: Understand that we can't optimize both criteria at the same time,  it's really more to optimize a weighted sum of both criteria.

Comment: @Susie: a weighted sum is a wrong idea. The optimum will be 100% of the solution with the best weight.

Comment: Hi, I have significantly re-phrased the question, converted it to a 2D problem, and added visualization. I believe it's now a much clearer question.

Comment: You still need to specify what your constraints are? Is the number of rectangles important and you want it to be minimal? Or rather the area or width/height or them maximal? How do you recognize a good solution?

Comment: Yes the above comment asks a fundamental question, how do you recognize a good solution? 

In order to approach I would ask two things: (1) a function that decide what if a solution is valid or not. (2) a function that given two solutions can decide which one is the best.

Comment: That's a good question. I would say there there two criterions to measure if a solution is good or not, the first one is how well the approximate large rectangles fit the grids, if we consider the value in each grid as the height of the grid, then we want the volume sum of the grids over volume of the large cuboids to be  greater than a certain percentage (say 70%). The second factor is how many rectangles are used, again, we would like it to be less than a max number, if feasible.

Comment: You could use an off-the-shelf regression tree fitting algorithm like XGBoost with a single tree.  This will allow you a lot of knobs to specify your "goodness of fit" and also regularize your solution by bounding aspects of the tree (max depth, min leaf size, etc...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idea of an algorithm to solve this (not optimally ofc):

1. examine **vertical** neighbours for each element that could be grouped. Rule of grouping needs to be determined by you after some "trial and error". Single-element groups are also possible. Every element must be added to one and only one group.
2. iterate through groups and check whether **horizontal** neighbours of those are "close enough", if yes, then merge groups.
3. iterate through groups and check whether **vertical** neighbours of those are "close enough", if yes, then merge groups.
4. Continue steps 2 and 3 and finish when there was no single group merging during those
5. Finally, remove those groups that do not fulfill  width/height requirements